# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_app' with heroku deployement

Tags: django, heroku, digital-ocean, modulenotfounderror

Hey mentors and senior devs
I am now on this issue 5-7 hours trying to solve it, This issue happens during the deployment of my app on digital oceans apps and these are logs that Heroku sent
please help me figure it out

````
2022-10-03T10:37:01.047248352Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-10-03T10:37:01.048342704Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: 
http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
2022-10-03T10:37:01.048420287Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-10-03T10:37:01.105225067Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with 
pid: 16
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121367774Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [16] [ERROR] Exception in worker 
process
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121405181Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121410503Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121414404Z     worker.init_process()
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121419137Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-``` 
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121423724Z     self.load_wsgi()
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121428153Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121431187Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121434180Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121438157Z     self.callable = self.load()
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121441663Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121462270Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121465690Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121469061Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121472387Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site- 
packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121475619Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121482753Z   File 
"/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121486027Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121490349Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in 
_gcd_import
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121493850Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in 
_find_and_load
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121497304Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in
````

_find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121501773Z   File "", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121505268Z   File "", line 1050, in
_gcd_import
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121508644Z   File "", line 1027, in
_find_and_load
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121511905Z   File "", line 1004, in
_find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121515248Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_app'
2022-10-03T10:37:01.121731498Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16)
2022-10-03T10:37:01.207224069Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-10-03T10:37:01.207265202Z [2022-10-03 10:37:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to
boot.
2022-10-03T10:37:04.348012028Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-10-03T10:37:04.349215146Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at:
http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
2022-10-03T10:37:04.349332842Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-10-03T10:37:04.391853564Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with
pid: 16
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406015762Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [16] [ERROR] Exception in worker
process
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406048084Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406055314Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406060597Z     worker.init_process()
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406066330Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406070425Z     self.load_wsgi()
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406073524Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406075830Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406078174Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406081378Z     self.callable = self.load()
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406083592Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406085923Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406089029Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406091677Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406093958Z   File "/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-
packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406096392Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406101142Z   File
"/workspace/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406103341Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406105924Z   File "", line 1050, in
_gcd_import
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406108164Z   File "", line 1027, in
_find_and_load
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406110635Z   File "", line 992, in
_find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406113766Z   File "", line 241, in
_call_with_frames_removed
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406116173Z   File "", line 1050, in
_gcd_import
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406118254Z   File "", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406120822Z   File "", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406122832Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_app'
2022-10-03T10:37:04.406270392Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16)
2022-10-03T10:37:04.482169771Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-10-03T10:37:04.482261239Z [2022-10-03 10:37:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to
boot.

```
in my requirements.txt

    asgiref==3.4.1
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
binary==1.0.0
dj-database-url==1.0.0
Django==3.2.15
django-bootstrap-v5==1.0.11
django-crispy-forms==1.13.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-request==1.6.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
importlib-metadata==4.8.3
Pillow==8.4.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.2.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing-extensions==4.1.1
whitenoise==5.3.0
zipp==3.6.0


settings

    """
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
import dj_database_url


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = False
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['cajetan.global', 'www.cajetan.global']







# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'users',
    'blog',
    'memberships',
    'dashboard',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap5',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cajetanglobalvisas.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'blog.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cajetanglobalvisas.wsgi.application'




DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False") == "True"

if DEVELOPMENT_MODE is True:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR/'static'),)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 587

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK= 'bootstrap4'

SITE_ID = 1

#change this in production
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = 'cajetanglobalvisa\messages'

# HTTPS settings
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True


# HSTS settings
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000 # 1 year
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

Comment: Is it your app name in django project

Comment: @ManojTolagekar yes

Comment: please provide the settings file and structure of your project

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I have updated with the settings file

Answer (score 1):

In the run command within Digital Ocean's settings, you need to change `django_app` in `gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm django_app.wsgi` (from the [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/)) to point to whichever app your Django app's wsgi.py file is in.

Answer (score 0):

You got module not found error because you have not added your app in installed apps in settings file.

To add do the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'users',
    'django_app', #added here
    'blog',
    'memberships',
    'dashboard',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap5',

]
```

Comment: When I did that it shifted to no module named django_heroku error

Comment: but before you got that error right

Comment: After I added what you suggested I add